# How can I calculate the text in one cell as a formula in another cell in microsoft excel?

Tags: excel

Here is what I want the Spreadsheet to look like.

```
       COLUMN A        COLUMN B        COLUMN C        COLUMN D
ROW1   hello           1               hello+hi        10
ROW2   hi              9               hello*hi        9
```

I want to be able to name the cell B1 after the text in cell A1 and the cell B2 after the text in the cell A2. Then I want to be able to compute the equations in column C and put the answers in column D.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do want to do that? Have you looked at `Define Name`?

Answer (score 0):

EVALUATE is available in VBA in all current versions

You can include it in you VBA code, or wrap it into a simple UDF to make it available as a worksheet function

```
Function ev(r As Range) As Variant
    ev = Evaluate(r.Value)
End Function
```

It basically treats the value of the passed parameter as an excel formula, same as if it were entered in a cell

`"11+5"` and `"=11+5"` will produce the same result

reference: https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula